# Android delete title from actionbar, delete name app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

When I want to "delete" the title (just the title, not the actionbar) of my first Activity, the name of my app was deleted too. (So I've just the "icon"...)

I did it, like that :

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

.....

```
    <activity
            android:name="PresentationActivity"
            android:logo="@drawable/logo"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

I don't understand why the app delete the label of my app ? I right setted it on

```
<application>
```

Any idea ?

thx

EDIT : I did it to hide the title when the activity is creating, but I don't like, because there is a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont like the delay then you can set the title color the same as background color ;) Its nasty hack, but it works if you dont have some gradient on background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the title, you can do it like this:

Go to your AndroidManifest and find the line that looks something like this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/something blah blah blah"
```

It'll be in your activity tag.

Change that to this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
```

Title gone :)

Is that what you wanted? I hope this helps. If not, let me know and I'll update my answer. :)

Comment: I think it was a good idea, but it's not available for API 13 :/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to disable title of ActionBar, you can either call code like this:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("");
```

or you can disable it

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: No, like I said, I don't like this solution because there is a delay before the title is hidden.

Comment: Well then you can declared this style item inside activity style:

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: Yes, I tried, but when i do it, the action bar disappear.

Comment: If you dont like the delay then you can set the title color the same as background color ;) Its nasty hack, but it works

Comment: Ok, I add it as another answer ;)